# Why does the ansible synchronize module doc page show relative paths only?

Tags: rsync, ansible

Here's an example:

```
# Synchronization of src on the control machine to dest on the remote hosts
- synchronize:
    src: some/relative/path
    dest: /some/absolute/path
```

What I'm guessing is, the relative path is how you specify a local src dir, i.e. a dir on the server you're running the ansible command from. But how do you configure a "base" dir? Do you have to run the playbook from the src dir? That seems dumb.

Does anyone use the synchronize module?

Comment: There are handful of examples with absolute src path in the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/synchronize_module.html).

Comment: Yes. And they seem not pertain to directories on the control machine, i.e. the machine where the command is being run.

Comment: Examples are not supposed to cover every possible case. Why not try it yourself and find out that absolute paths work as well. If you think, this should be added to the documentation, you are free to file an issue and pull-request to [ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible) repo.

Comment: I think the examples ought to cover the most common scenarios rather than the more advanced implementations. I believe most new users are going to be pushing files from a local repo/dir.

Comment: The common module to copy files from control host to remote host is the [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) module. If you need to use the synchronize module the way you intent to you likely have lots of files in your Ansible repository. Which is IMHO for many use cases a bad idea. IMHO you should keep configuration data (few files) separate from application data (data for which you might need synchronize) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really suck. I just needed to learn how to use the copy module in recursive mode. If I had millions of files to sync, I would use synchronize.

```
- name: copy nagios plugins and snmp mibs
      copy:
        src: /home/ansible/DEPLOY/usr/
        dest: /usr
        owner: root
        group: root
```